# Custom Error Display At Custom Place rather than next to Each Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have This Jquery ssed in my Page,where i will be getting error message based on ruleset.
It Works Fine!! Just Need To Know What Changes can i make to get error message at the bottom of the page instead of getting near each and every textbox.

Need Error Message next to submit button and highlight to which textbox  the error states would be much appreciated if their is multiple error

```
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <script>
    var ruleSet1 = {
            required: true

            };
        var ruleSet3 = {
                minlength: 5,
            };

        $( '#AddReport').validate({
          rules:{

        ReportID: ruleSet1,
        TaskID: ruleSet1,
        Assist: ruleSet3,
        Guide: ruleSet3,
        DateInput: ruleSet1,
        ButtonCreationDemoInput2: ruleSet1,
        ButtonCreationDemoInput: ruleSet1,
        RefNo: ruleSet3,
        Remarks: ruleSet3,
        EDocNo: ruleSet3,
        WorkLocation: ruleSet1,
        Content: ruleSet3

             }
         });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `errorPlacement`. This property takes function in which you can define where errors need to go in DOM.

DOC: http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/

Example from doc:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
  }
});
```

Comment: and instead of td,i think i can provide it to div or span.right? since i haven't used table in this page structure it would be hard to place table just bcz to show errors.

Comment: Yes, you can use any element you want :)
It's just example.

Comment: error.appendTo( "errors"); consider i have span tag with name 'errors' and it should come according to this. But its not taking!!

Comment: $( '#AddReport' ).validate({
  rules: {

 ReportID: ruleSet1,
 TaskID: ruleSet1,
  }
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo( "#errors");
  }
 });

Comment: Name or class/id? Meybe some little mistake?
`error.appendTo( '.errors' )` ?

Comment: am sorry,ya id. i just edited my previous comment its ("#errors") still not working

Comment: If it's your real code, so you are missing comma before `errorPlacement`